# Xcode 14 unit testing clone simulator

Tags: xcode14

In Xcode 14, running unit testing seems to be creating simulator 'clones' (named 'Clone 1/2.. of iPhone').
On older machines, this can take a long time. This is happening every time when switching from running the App and running tests.
For example, running the App will launch the Simulator. Running tests will launch new one or more Simulators (Clone of ...), and running the App again will reload the original Simulator.
Any way to control this? This makes running tests a real pain on older machines.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a setting for this in the Xcode build scheme. Click the scheme name in the toolbar of your project window, then go to Edit Scheme -> Test -> *<your Test target>* -> Options... and uncheck "Execute in parallel (if possible)".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I had 'Execute in parallel' unchecked. Could be a bug with 14.0 (parallel testing has been available since Xcode 10).

Comment: yeah, potentially. it's surprise that the clones are showing now, which i  think should be hidden in the background. it's kind of annoying to populate your screen with clones of simulator.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 15, the relevant setting is in a different place:

1. Edit Scheme -> Test -> Test Plans -> (Your Plan) -> (Your Target) -> Options...
2. Uncheck "Execute in parallel (if possible)"
3. If prompted, press OK to save changes in a manual test plan.